# How can i remove \n\r from a string?

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
if (t == obj)
{
    LocalyKeyWords.Remove(tokens[0]);
}
```

The variable `t` is `string` and also `obj` is `string`.
In some cases im using a breakpoint and see that obj in the end contain `\n\r` so I want to check that if the string obj contain `\n\r` remove the `\n\r` then make the comparison of `t == obj`

How can I do it ?

Comment: are you sure it's not `\r\n`?

Comment: @Default Well, I have actually seen instances of "\n\r", so that's *possible*, but not as likely.  If you're accepting input from an unknown source you should be robust enough to handle any combinations of `\n` and `\r`.

Comment: @Servy didn't know that.. I thought that there was some guidelines regarding newline at least between Windows <> Windows and Unix <> Unix.

Comment: @Default Yep, and there are lots of people that violate the guidelines, sometimes by accident, sometimes not.  At this point programs really should be prepared for almost anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
myString = myString.Replace("\n", string.Empty).Replace("\r", string.Empty);
```

Comment: And what happens when someone has a newline character other than "\r\n", such as just "\n"?

Comment: @Servy they can replace them individually

Comment: Yes, they can.  If you want to remove all newlines from the entire string that's what you *have* to do.

Comment: And you're not doing that.

Comment: @Servy While the question only asked for "\n\r" specifically, I should have been more thorough in my answer and looked at his intention more carefully. Edited.

Answer (score 3):

`Trim` removes whitespace from the beginning and end of a string, so if you only want to remove whitespace from the ends I'd suggest using that:

```
if (t.Trim() == obj.Trim())
```

If you must remove all newline characters from the entire string then you can use this:

```
public static string RemoveNewlines(string input)
{
    return input.Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", "");
}
```

As that function will be able to handle any type of newline character, be it `\n`, `\r\n`, `\r`, or even a combination of several.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to get rid of unwanted characters is to [Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx) them with an empty string

Answer (score 0):

just use this

```
t = t.Replace("\r\n", string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 0):

If this variables are in the very begin or end of your string you should use
 [`string.Trim`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trim.aspx) otherwise simple [`string.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx).